# Change PayPal REST Endpoint

Tags: api, rest, paypal, endpoint

So I've been working on a PayPal REST API application, working in the sandbox environment just fine, but now it's time to switch over to Live and I'm having some issues.  I have changed my ClientID and Secret from Sandbox to Live, but the application is still trying to hit the `api.sandbox.paypal.com` endpoint instead of the `api.paypal.com` endpoint.

This results in a 401 Error:

```
object(PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException)#24 (9){  
   [  
      "url":      "PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException":private
   ]   => string(46) "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"   [  
      "data":      "PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException":private
   ]   => string(77) "   {  
      "error":"invalid_client",
      "error_description":"Client Authentication failed"
   }   " ["   message":protected
]=> string(89) "Got Http response code 401 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token."[  
   "string":   "Exception":private
```

If I switch back in the Sandbox Ids, it works fine.  Do I need to manually set the endpoint somewhere?  I was under the impression the API would understand which is a SandboxId and LiveId.

Answer (score 1):

Found some documentation on this.  Turns out you need to set the mode as part of the ApiContext for a live environment using the setConfig Method.

Example:

```
$paypal = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        $clientIdLive,
        $secretIdLive
    )
);

$paypal->setConfig(
  array(
    'mode' => 'live',
    'log.LogEnabled' => true,
    'log.FileName' => 'PayPal.log',
    'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
  )
);
```